# Pass arrayList to setMultiChoiceItems in dialog

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-dialog

I am implementing a simple dialog with a checked `listview` in it. This is what I've done so far:

```
CharSequence[] items = {"Brand A", "Brand B", "Brand C"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StrengthOfDemandsView.this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Brands");
    final ArrayList seletedItems=new ArrayList();

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which checkbox checked)
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

                        seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                    } else{
                        seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                    }
                }
            })

         .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

**PROBLEM:**

Initially, I'm passing an Array to `setMultiChoiceItems` method and it works fine but how to pass an `ArrayList` instead of an array? Like this:

```
ArrayList<Products> brandList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Whenever I'm trying to pass an `ArrayList` to `setMultiChoiceItems` method it gives me this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'setMultiChoiceItems(java.util.ArrayList<com.application.marketvisit.dataItem.Products>, null, anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)'
```

Comment: Create new array with Strings and add on adapter

Comment: yes I'm working now on arrayadapter I'll post the solution if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a `String` array to [`AlertDialog.Builder#setMultiChoiceItems`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20boolean[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener))so collect it as a String array

```
String arr = new String[brandList.size()];
for(int i=0 ; i< brandList.size();i++){
    arr[i] = brandList.get(i).getProductName();
   //getProductName or any suitable method
}
```

Comment: I'll populate the names by implementing your solution but the reason why I want to use ArrayList is because I want the database IDs of the checked products. Thanks for the solution though!

Comment: there is no way that you can pass a POJO list although  use `indexSelected` to fetch the corresponding item from `brandList` list and fetch the id

Comment: Ohhh! I was so stupid to ask that question in the first place!. Thanks, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @3iL i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this...and let me know if it works..

```
 ArrayList<String> strBrandList = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < brandList.size(); i++) {
           strBrandList.add(brandList.get(i).getProductName())
   }
```